# How to get python to recognize missing value when converting list to dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

Working in Python and I've tried a number of different variations but this is my latest. I'm trying to convert "user" list to a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    "Grae Drake": 98110,
    "Bethany Kok": None,
    "Alex Nussbacher": 94101,
    "Darrell Silver": 11201,    
}
```

It would show the user's name and zip code, but one user is missing a zip code so I want it to show 'None' where the zip code is missing. Converting isn't the issue, but I'm trying to make it more dynamic in that it will recognize the missing zip code and input 'None' instead.

```
users = [["Grae Drake", 98110], ["Bethany Kok"], ["Alex Nussbacher", 94101], ["Darrell Silver", 11201]]

def user_contacts():
  for name, z in users:
    [None if z is None else z for z in users]
  user_dict = dict(users)
  return user_dict
```

Comment: ```b = {i[0] : i[1] if len(i) == 2 else None for i in users}```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
users = [["Grae Drake", 98110], ["Bethany Kok"], ["Alex Nussbacher", 94101], ["Darrell Silver", 11201]]

d = dict((u + [None])[:2] for u in users)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'Grae Drake': 98110, 'Bethany Kok': None, 'Alex Nussbacher': 94101, 'Darrell Silver': 11201}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked, thank you! If not too much could you explain WHY this worked? I'm new to Python and I see all the pieces but need a little more to understand how they fit together.

Comment: @DavidS All depends, how [dict()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict) works - here, it needs an iterable that returns two elements - `(key, value)`. I add to each value in list `users` a `None` value and then take first two elements.

Comment: Ahh I see that makes sense! Appreciate the help!